# How to set base url without setting virtualhost?

Tags: php, url, localhost, virtualhost

I have my site, for example `www.example.com/en` , and

```
$url_part = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$lang = $url_part[0];
```

Variable `$lang` contains string "`en`".

If I run it on local server, url will be `localhost/example/en`, and `$lang` variable now contains "example". 
Can I solve this without setting `VirtualHost`?

Or everybody who wants to use this project have to set VirtualHost?
Thanks

Comment: What you want to solve? You want to return `en` independently from the url which it comes from?

Comment: yes. I want $lang to contain language,.

Answer (score 0):

Using **regular expresion**, you can achieve the goal as below :

```
<?php

 preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $reg);
 echo $reg[0]; 

?>
```

> Output=> **en**